# awk + cut file between lines from ext ARG

Tags: awk

I have the following awk commnad
I want to cut the file from start to end
please advice why awk not work

```
   awk -v PARAM=start -v PARAM1=end '/PARAM/,/PARAM1/' file
```

file:

```
2324
443
start
43
end
545
```

required file

```
start
43
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables between slashes. Use the match operator `~` or the equality operator `==`:

```
awk -v PARAM=start -v PARAM1=end '$0 ~ PARAM,$0 ~ PARAM1' file
```

or

```
awk -v PARAM=start -v PARAM1=end '$0 == PARAM,$0 == PARAM1' file
```